# How to populate vector within function?

Tags: r

Purpose of below code is to populate vector `textVector` with results of system commands that are contained in a seperate vector `tv` :

```
tv = c("ls" , "ls -l")
textVector = c()

mf <- function(f) {
  cmdToRun <- f
  aa <- system(cmdToRun , intern=TRUE)
  textVector <- c(textVector, aa)
}

lapply(tv , mf)
```

This code is not behaving as expected as `textVector` just contains NULL

How to populate `textVector` with results of system commands ?

Using :

```
tv = c("ls" , "ls -l")
textVector = c()

mf <- function(f) {
  cmdToRun <- f
  aa <- system(cmdToRun , intern=TRUE)

  textVector <<- c(textVector, aa)

}

lapply(tv , mf)
```

results with `textVector` containing results just of first command , in this case "ls" and not results of "ls -l"

Comment: I've tested my answer on both Linux and Windows - it works. I am curious to know why it doesn't work for you.  Check .bashrc file if you are on *uni system.

Comment: You should mention that you are "Using" my answer. Else it can appear that I am just posting your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change an object in a parent environment within a function, you need to use `<<-` instead of `<-`.

```
tv = c("ls" , "ls -l")
textVector = c()

mf <- function(f) {
  cmdToRun <- f
  aa <- system(cmdToRun , intern=TRUE)

  textVector <<- c(textVector, aa)

}

lapply(tv , mf)
```

Results: directory contain two files "file1" and "file2"

```
textVector
#[1] "file1"
#[2] "file2"
#[3] "total 8"
#[4] "-rw-r--r-- 1 [deleted] 3 Nov  6 18:24 file1"
#[5] "-rw-r--r-- 1 [deleted] 5 Nov  6 18:24 file2"
```

Comment: thanks, seems textVector contains results just of first command , in this case "ls" and not results of "ls -l"

Comment: it worked for me... I have results for with both ls and ls -l in the textVector.

Comment: @blue-sky I've `rm(list=ls())` and the ran the code in a folder. Results attached.

Answer (score 2):

You have to save the result of your `lapply`call into a new variable ... in your case it will result in a list with two character vectors

```
result<-lapply(tv , mf)
```

Moreover it depends on your OS whether `system` will work or not ... r docu suggests `system2`you might also get lucky with `shell`